# How to get last object from List<> in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have below condition in my C# 2.0.

There is some VbScript code:

```
For i = 0 to UBound(components) - 1

    If i = UBound(Components) - 1 Then
        WriteOut "<div class=""clearBoth""></div>"
    End If  
Next
```

Below I am trying to write in C#, please suggest what condition will be written for "If i = UBound(Components) - 1 Then" in c#.

```
List<tc.ComponentPresentation> cmp = new List<tc.ComponentPresentation>();

foreach (tc.ComponentPresentation cm in cmp)
{
    //Here I want to right one condition that

    if(this is the last object in "cmp" list)
    {
        ////do something
    }
}
```

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to use the indexer instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmp.Count; i++)
{
    var cm = cmp[i];
    if (i == cmp.Count - 1)
    {
        // Handle the last value differently
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use something like the ["smart enumerations"](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2007/07/27/smart-enumerations.aspx) from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil), which lets you use a `foreach` loop but still access the "is first", "is last", and "index" for each entry. With C# 3 it's actually somewhat simpler to use than the code in that blog post:

```
foreach (var entry in SmartEnumerable.Create(cmp))
{
    var cm = entry.Value;
    if (entry.IsLast)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

(As an aside, `tc` is an odd namespace name...)

EDIT: Note that checking whether your current item is *equal to* the last item in the list is *not* a reliable indication that you're currently on the last iteration. It will only work if the list contains distinct elements. Both of the approaches above really tell you whether you're on the last iteration, which is what I assumed you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (cmp[cmp.Count - 1] == cm)
```

That should work.

Comment: You're assuming the list is of unique elements. That could evaluate to true for every item in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

```
tc.ComponentPresentation lastItem = cmp[cmp.Count - 1];
```

Comment: And therefore the `if` condition should be `if (cm == lastItem)`

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Except that (as per my comment to Kristian) that's not necessarily a reliable indication that you're currently dealing with the last item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
cmp[cmp.Count - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the 'foreach' loop into a 'for' loop and use the indexer for the loop to copare to cmp.Length

Comment: can you please suggest with for loop?

Comment: @Manu: See my answer, which does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to **iterate** through the list?

If you want to work with the last element then just use

```
tc.ComponentPresentation cp = cmp[cmp.Count - 1];
//Do anything with cp here
```

That's it